# How many solutions are there of the congruence $x^3 ≡ 1 \pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p > 3$ be prime. How many solutions are there of the congruence $$x^3 ≡ 1 \pmod p?$$

Comment: Three if $p-1$ is divisible by $3$ and one otherwise.

Comment: Hint : Legendre symbol and Law of quadratic reciprocity

Answer (score 4):

Consider the group of units mod p under multiplication.  Because $\mathbb Z/p$ is a field, $G=(\mathbb Z/p)^*$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $p-1$, and cubing becomes multiplication by $3$.  Phrasing things in terms of this additive notation makes things easier to solve.

If $\gcd(3,p-1)$, then multiplication by $3$ is invertible mod (p-1), and so the equation $3x=0$ has only one solution.  However, if $3|p-1$, then not only is $0$ a solution to $3x=0$, but so is $(p-1)/3$ and $2(p-1)/3$.

Answer (score 4):

$x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1) \pmod{p}$

since p Prime, so $x≡1 \pmod{p}$ or $x^2 + x + 1≡0 \pmod{p}$

$x^2 + x + 1 = \frac{(2x+1)^2 + 3}{4} ≡ 0 \pmod{p}$

so we try to find if the equation $y^2 ≡ -3 \pmod{p}$ has root or not:

$y^2 ≡ -3 \pmod{p} $ has root $\Leftrightarrow$ $\left( \frac{-3}{p}\right) = 1$

Consider **Law of quadratic reciprocity**

$\left( \frac{-3}{p}\right) \left( \frac{p}{-3}\right) = (-1)^{p-1}$

and

$\left( \frac{-1}{p}\right) = (-1)^{p-1}$

so

$\left( \frac{p}{3}\right) = 1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $y^2 ≡ -3 \pmod{p}$ has root

$\Rightarrow p=3k+1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $y^2 ≡ -3 \pmod{p}$ has root

$\Rightarrow$ $|root| = 3$ if $p = 3k+1$  otherwise $1$